# What happens when someone is blacklisted?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, blocklist

Just wanted to find out what happens when someone is blacklisted or has a post-ban. Is it only their login that is blacklisted or also their IP address?

Comment: What do you mean by blacklisted? Someone who has a post-ban?

Comment: @Bart: Yes. Sorry, I'll edit my question

Comment: We're unlikely to get detailed information about this because it might help banned people to circumvent the ban.

Comment: Presumably the IP (and possibly email address) gets a permanent ban.  But I doubt anyone will want to answer this because of what @Pekka suggested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is roughly what happens:

[image: Blackballed again]

See also: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Comment: -1 we should not behave like that with cat:P

Comment: +1 [Cats are a plague](http://www.spiegel.de/international/germany/killer-cats-threaten-the-world-s-endangered-species-a-881978.html) and some sort of control needs to happen. Enough of kittens.

Comment: Any cat incapable of ninjalike acts of dodging, and ballarina like grace is obviously unworthy of the name. If they can be bothered to get up